# how to show Author group not Author name

Tags: plugins, author, multi-author

i own blog which me and some of my friends write posts on it and i allow guests to write there own posts
put under evey post we shows Author name i want to add me and all my friends to a group and every post one of us write display ower group name not Author name.
how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Edit each user via the Admin pages. Change the "Nickname" field to what you want to appear. Then use the "Display Name Publicly As" dropdown to select the nickname. Do this for each user.

Comment: but with this way i'll just make all authors the same name i don't want to do this i want to show for example the author cnn reporters and when some one click on this group name will drive him to lest of authors in the cnn reporter group

Comment: No, each author can have their own 'nickname'. You could set up nicknames of "Joe Smith, Author Group" and "Mary Jones, Author Group" for those two users. If you want to have one 'global' user account for posting, then have everyone log in and post via that one user name.